# Magento's $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay() Method

Tags: php, magento

I'm investigating Magento's infamous price block/`price.phtml` file, and I've run into something that looks like a bug and/or abandoned code path, but I'd like to run it by the community first to make sure I understand what's happening.

Throughout this file, Magento will use the following method in conditional calls

```
$_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)
$_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)
$_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)
$_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)
```

From what my code tracing has gathered, this method (as called) ultimately compares the second paramater with one of two configuration values.  Either

```
Tax -> Fixed Product Taxes -> Display Prices On Product View Page
Tax -> Fixed Product Taxes -> Display Prices In Product Lists
```

depending on the current context.  If we're on a product page, it's the first.  Otherwise, it assumes a product list page.  (and "on a product page" means there's a value set in `Mage::registry('current_product')`).

This is all well and good **except** for the following call

```
$_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)
```

The only possible values for these configuration fields are 0 - 3.  There is no "4".

So, first question: Does the above accurately describe the behavior of the `typeOfDisplay` method? (assuming `null` for the `$zone` paramater)

Second question: If so, were there (or are there) versions of Magento where a value of "4" was stored in either the

```
Tax -> Fixed Product Taxes -> Display Prices In Product Lists
Tax -> Fixed Product Taxes -> Display Prices On Product View Page
```

field?

Comment: Checking in CE 1.6.2.0.  Where are you seeing 0 - 3 as the possible configuration values?  The only thing I see in config.xml is that all the `default/tax/weee/*` values are defaulted to zero.  It looks like the `$product` parameter in the `typeOfDisplay()` function definition isn't even used within the function, which is interesting.

Comment: Sparcksoft — Look in the backend system configuration section.  The possible values I'm talking about are the drop down values in Tax -> Fixed Product Taxes -> Display Prices In Product Lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, maybe this is a partial answer...

In CE 1.3.3.0, there does appear to be a value for `4`.

```
class Mage_Weee_Model_Config_Source_Display
{

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value'=>0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('weee')->__('Including FPT only')),
            array('value'=>1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('weee')->__('Including FPT and FPT description [excl. FPT VAT]')),
            array('value'=>4, 'label'=>Mage::helper('weee')->__('Including FPT and FPT description [incl. FPT VAT]')),
            array('value'=>2, 'label'=>Mage::helper('weee')->__('Excluding FPT, FPT description, final price')),
            array('value'=>3, 'label'=>Mage::helper('weee')->__('Excluding FPT')),
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually that's all the answer I need. Since there was a value of "4" at one time, and price.phtml looks like one of those files people are frightened to re-factor, that explains everything. Thanks!